# How can I differentiate between a junior employee and a senior employee at work?

Tags: management, communication, colleagues, team-role

In an attempt to navigate the workplace, I am looking to see if there are definable attributes between a Junior employee and Senior employees. I am trying to use this information to navigate a workforce without titles. So I will be on the look out for attributes, behaviour & responsibilities.

Comment: I would define "senior" and "junior" according to the level of experience. Where it gets tricky to define is whether you're counting experience in the industry, in the particular company, or in a particular team in the company (e.g. if you work for a company 10 years and then change teams, do you become a "junior" in the new team?). Some companies also include the term "senior" and "junior" in job titles. Only in that case is the meaning of the terms really well-defined.

Comment: This is the purpose the lack of establishment in the title might be leaning in your case of lack of definition. If we take a step back from years, are their distinct activities a senior would do a junior would not be expected to do?

Comment: I'm voting to close because while on the face of it this is an interesting question, I don't see how it can be answered in any meaningful way. Junior/Senior denominations are approached differently at every company as are (management) responsibilities, while behaviorism should be left to psychologists.

Comment: I don't see where the complexity is - if the company doesn't apply junior/senior titles, then everyone is the same level. sure, respect experience, but if you've been brought into the job, you have the same weight in discussions as the guy who's been there longer - i had this at my first job where all engineers were the same grade, even if they had been there only a year or 20 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you define this by the complexity of the work they do within their professional specialty and the level of responsibility for results they have. A big difference between Junior and Senior also tends to happen in the level of supervisory/technical oversight they have. Seniors are allowed more responsibility for making final technical decisions and overall design of products, policies, software, etc.

Perhaps this answer in another forum would help you see what I am talking about. (The link is specific to software dev, but there are similar progressions in other professions)
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14914/whats-the-difference-between-entry-level-jr-sr-developers/14972#14972

Answer (score 3):

> I am looking to see if there are definable attributes between a Junior
>   employee and Senior employees. I am trying to use this information to
>   navigate a workforce without titles.

If there are no titles, then there are no "Junior" or "Senior" employees.

But you could use any or all of the attributes to arbitrarily divide folks for your personal needs

- years of experience in your industry
- years of experience in your company
- your assessment of their level of knowledge
- their "political connectedness" within the company
- how others (such as your peers) treat them
- the nature of the projects they are assigned
- the nature of the role they fill

Comment: This is interesting, but I do believe even without titles teams depend on people of all attributes to create a diverse and meaningful workplace.

Comment: Hmmm... I believe that may have been due to some mind chatter as text. I was trying to say even without the titles people are playing specific roles along their progression. If I have a person who is 1 year into their career they are for want of a better term Junior.

Comment: @JaiCB  I think the point of Joe's list is that you can consider many attributes to form a conclusion about someone. Having 1 year of industry experience is just *one* attribute. Suppose an employee has 10 years of experience. Does that automatically make him "senior"?

Comment: It most definitely does not as your company can define this to their liking. This has been a useful discussion thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, senior employees will have more tenure, which implies more experience and knowledge. That is what a "senior" title is supposed to indicate.

The best way to tell the difference? If you find yourself going to other employees to ask questions about stuff, then consider them to be senior, and consider yourself junior.